# Convert txt data in json format in linux

Tags: linux, unix

I have some data in a text file which I want to convert to JSON format

```
Gender = Male
color = green
-----------------------

Age = 24
city = NY
-----------------------

Profile = Blogger
exp = 5
```

Out of the entire file I only need a few details in JSON:

```json
{
    "Gender": "Male",
    "City": "NY",
    "exp": "5"
}
```

How can I only take a few pieces of information from the text and display it in JSON format using Linux?

Answer (score 0):

You could grep the name value pairs you're interested in and pass that to `jq`:

```bash
egrep -i '^(gender|city|exp)\s*=' input | \
jq --raw-input 'split("\\s*=\\s*"; "") | { (.[0]): .[1] }' | \
jq --slurp add
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Gender": "Male",
  "city": "NY",
  "exp": "5"
}
```